# Getting a loading gif to display during a large javascript array search

Tags: javascript

I have a problem getting a loading gif to display during a large javascript array search. The screen can hang for a few seconds if there are a lot of entries returned.

I managed to pick up a function to show and hide the loading gif, but when I try and call it before the search, it doesn't seem to show in time. Any advise? Thanks :)

Show/hide image function:

```
function setImageVisible(id, visible) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    img.style.visibility = (visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
}
```

The search function:

```
function finnishSearch(val){

var result = document.getElementById('result');
result.innerHTML = '';

if(val && val.length > 2){
    setImageVisible('loading', true);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var ss = arr[i][0].toString().substring(0,val.length); // ss (SubString) checks the number of characters currently typed 
        if(ss.toLowerCase() === val.toLowerCase()){ // check substring against the user input
            var res = arr[i][1]; 
            var reg = eval('/'+val+'/i');
            var found = arr[i][0].replace(reg, '<span class="r">$&<\/span>');
            if(result.innerHTML.length > 0){
                result.innerHTML += '.<br />';
            }
            result.innerHTML += found + '<b>' + ' > ' + '</b>' + '<span class="g">' + res + '<\/span>';
        }
    }
    setImageVisible('loading', false);
}
else {return;}
}
```

The image originally hidden:

```
<img id="loading" style="visibility:hidden" src="images/loading_reduced.gif" alt="" />
```

Comment: Javascript is synchronous, but your browser may not be able to react to the update of the image if your search is blocking the thread. For long running/intensive tasks you should use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers)

Comment: Try calling the `finnishSearch()` with a `setTimeout(finnishSearch, 0);`. That pushes the function down the queue. You have to call the `setImageVisible()` then from outside that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give time back to the browser, so make your crunch function recallable and use setTimeout with some sleep time (10 or more ms).